# (Python + MySQL) Inserir a senha do banco automaticamente em um dump

Tags: mysql, python, backup, cron, dump

Estou criando um script em Python que faz um backup da base de dados da empresa em que trabalho e ele irá rodar no crontab semanalmente.

**Minha dúvida:**

Como inserir a senha automaticamente, já que ela é requisitada depois do comando mysqldump??

**Como o código está atualmente:**

```
import subprocess

import os

command = 'mysqldump -u root -p testes_script > testandoo.sql'

os.system(command)
subprocess.Popen('senhatestes')

print('Dump realizado com sucesso')
```

**Retorno ao executar o código:**

```
Enter password:
```

Tentei executar um subprocess.Popen('senha') porém não tive sucesso, o erro retornado é:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste_dump.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen('senhatestes')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in _init_
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'senhatestes': 'senhatestes'
```

Esta é apenas uma versão de testes, preciso fazer este dump rolar antes de escrever efetivamente o código que vou rodar em produção.

Comment: Não cumprimente, não agradeça e não assine as publicações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estiver usando linux (Ubuntu), tudo que precisa é criar um um arquivo `.my.cnf` em sua home.

```
touch ~/.my.cnf
```

Preencher o arquivo `.my.cnf`, com seguinte conteúdo:

```
[mysqldump]
user = mysqluser
password = senhasuperseguradoseubancodedadosT0p+
```

Mudar a permissão do arquivo criado (`~/.my.cnf`) via chmod para 600, isso vai prevenir outros usuário de ver o conteúdo do arquivo.

```
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf
```

Agora ao executar o `mysqldump`, ao passar o parâmetro `-p` a senha não será mais solicitada, pois será lida do arquivo.

```
mysqldump -u mysqluser -p > testandoo.sql
```

Repare que neste exemplo estou utilizando outro usuário.

Os passos demonstrados aqui podem ser visto neste [link](https://www.techiecorner.com/1619/how-to-setup-mysqldump-without-password-in-cronjob/).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição. Funcionou perfeitamente e resolveu meu problema.